# Ethernet speed Capped at 100 mbps

Tags: internet, lan, home-networking

I have CAT 6 UTP cable. When i connect it via LAN to my laptop, it shows 100 mbps only, whereas my plan is of 200 mbps. My laptop does support gigabyte connection. The default cable with the router when connected to the main ONT device, shows 200 mbps. I changed the settings for my ethernet to 1 Gbps, which means the speed is not capped by my laptop. What could be possibly wrong? can this be because of bad crimping? The cable is only 40m long

Comment: *The default cable with the router when connected to the main ONT device, shows 200 mbps.* Maybe it shows 100 Mbps IN + 100 Mbps OUT = 200 Mbps? *can this be because of bad crimping?* Yes. Try to connect staying near the router and using tested patchcord. And check that router's built-in LAN socket is not damaged.

Comment: I tested my router with shorter cable which comes with the router itself. I got 200 mbps download speed. Which means that the LAN socket is also not damaged.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 likely candidates for the problem -

1. The cable is not good enough or is faulty - This is where I would put my money.  If some of the wires are not properly connected it is entirely possible for the ethernet connection to work but be limited to 100 megabits.    It is somewhat less likely, but technically speaking I believe a 40 meter long cable is out of spec and might not work - The spec calls for a maximum length of 100 meters, but of that, a maximum length of only 10 meters for stranded cable (ie 2 patch leads of up to 5 meters each + 90 meters solid core)
2. It is possible that the router does not have the performance to move the number of packets required to get to 200 megabit.

Comment: You can get cheap cable testers which can test out continuity of all wires, and that can be helpful with diagnosing problems like this one.

Comment: I once had a cable that was supposed to be Cat5E but always dropped to 100 Mbps after a minute or so. I've cut it and the pairs weren't even twisted. Moral of the story: don't believe what's printed on the cable.

Comment: @gronostaj I had same experience with cat 5e XD. But my cable does have 4 pair and is bulkier than the cat 5. I dont think there is any issue with the cable category.

Comment: @davidgo I tested my router with short cable that we get in the box. It provided more than 200 mbps. So router is surely capable of delivering the speed. Is it possible that the router might not be able to deliver 200 mbps because the cable is long? (40m)

Comment: If the cable is out of spec then the speed may be slower then 200 meg, but thats not the routers fault (and its unlikely but not impossible replacing the cable will fix it).  It sounds very much like a cable issue - especially if it was crimped by hand.